# Am I using HAD wrong? If so, why?

Tags: meaning

I made a comment about a certain event in Warfare History and THOUGHT that I was correct in my decision to leave out an adjective in it because I thought that the verb HAD had an open ended "branch" in it's definition(s). But after doing a quick search on the google machine, it looks like I may have made a mistake. As you'll see below:

> @6204 Are you seriously comparing a few million mediteranian inhabitants, to the almost entire "empire" worth of support the USSR had for Stalingrad?

user's shortened response:

> @ME  Erm no the urban combat in Stalingrad involved the 6th Army and the 62nd Army. Neither side committed their "empires" to that offensive...

when I used HAD in my comment I meant: "..had potential for...". But thought that because the word HAD is not absolute in it's possession of x/y/z past tense object, that it would have communicated just the same with out needing to add the adjective POTENTIAL.

Can someone just confirm that there is no situation where the word HAD is not absolute in it's definition for past tense POSSESSION of x/y/z object?

Comment: Why would a reader assume that you meant _had potential for_ when you haven't previously mentioned potential? I would understand the object of _had_ to be _support_. (BTW it's 'Mediterranean'.)

Comment: Hi Max, can you try to [edit] out some of the superfluous information here? You can just quote your comment and ask if "had" can be understood as meaning "had potential for".

Comment: I don't know why I can't directly reply to comments on this platform, so I'll just use this comment box to reply to @KateBunting: If you reread the second to last paragraph, you'll see why. Yea, I knew something was off when I wrote that name, it's that second "r" that gets me.

Comment: @Joachim: I wrote it (as the website instructions said to) with as much detail as possible for context & meaning sake. I wouldn't know what is "superfluous" about this post, even if I tried.

Comment: How do you mean "had" is "not absolute in its possession"? Can you give an example where "have" is not "absolute in its possession"?

Comment: It sounds like the other side is differing with the factual content of your claim: you offer up a hypothetical and they are saying the hypothetical isn't relevant. There are all kinds of potential things, some of which are probable or improbable, some of which might be ruled out by their effect elsewhere, some of which aren't worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't appear to use it incorrectly, as your sentence makes both grammatical and logical sense. However, your own understanding of what you think you mean doesn't match what you said, so perhaps in that sense you are using it incorrectly.

"Have", meaning *to possess*, is a *transitive verb* in all its forms, meaning it must have a direct object - for example, "*my father had a dog*". You couldn't just say "my father had." He had what? So, I don't know what you could mean by the verb being "open-ended". You cannot use the verb without specifying what the subject possesses.

The object doesn't always follow the verb - it can be previously stated. For example:

- My father had a dog named Rover.
- Rover is a dog my father had.

Your example is like this - the object is stated before the verb. So, what you said was in effect meaning this:

> the USSR had [almost an entire "empire" worth of support] for Stalingrad.

What you think you mean - about *potential* - isn't stated or implied, so there is no way any English speaker would think you meant that. If what you said they had was just hypothetical then perhaps you should have used the word 'potential':

> Are you seriously comparing a few million Mediterranean inhabitants, to the *potential* "empire" worth of support the USSR had for Stalingrad?

Did you maybe think that the word 'almost' was providing the same meaning? It doesn't - "almost an empire's worth" suggest that *most* of the empire actually supported it.

Comment: " "Have", meaning to possess, is a transitive verb in all its forms, meaning it must have a direct object - for example, "my father had a dog". You couldn't just say "my father had." He had what? So, I don't know what you could mean by the verb being "open-ended". You cannot use the verb without specifying what the subject possesses. " - This Answered the question; Can someone just confirm that there is no situation where the word HAD is not absolute in it's definition for past tense POSSESSION of x/y/z object?

Comment: " Did you maybe think that the word 'almost' was providing the same meaning? " - No I didn't because I understood what you said to be the case, If I did. What I am trying to communicate is: Are you seriously comparing a few million Mediterranean inhabitants, to the potential "empire" worth of population support the USSR could of had the potential to use for Stalingrad, if it wanted/needed too? - My intent is to communicate that the USSR COULD of HAD more support for that city, in the PAST TENSE, but without so much verbage.

Comment: @MaxR. "Had" is the past participle of the verb *to have*, so yes it can only refer to past tense possession in this usage. There are situations where you could reply "I have" to a question like "Do you have a pen?" because the object of your reply is implied in the question you respond to. Ultimately, there is always an object.